# uso del inplace en una instrucción en pandas

Tags: pandas

he escrito la siguiente línea:

final_df[' Computer_OS'] = np.where(final_df[' Computer_OS'] == " ","no registrado", inplace = True )

Mi idea es que en una columna que tiene celdas vacias se cambie el valor por el texto "no registrado"

pero me sale el siguiente error:

TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'

porque no me acepta el inplace, cómo debería escribirlo para que lo acepte?

Comment: simplemente ese parámetro no existe. Recuerda que estas escribiendo una sentencia de numpy y no de pandas.